# Unknown Length Array, Assigning Any Part Of The Array Any Time

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, q-learning

I am working with Q-Learning and want a 3D policy gradient that is completely empty until the the AI needs to access it. 
This is because my state is three inputs that each could be any integer from 1 to infinity, each number above 1 being increasingly less probable.

Hopefully this is possible. I am also not looking for the code to be handed to me, just hope someone can point me in the right direction.

```
policyGradient = [][][]
policyGradient[5][10][15] = 0.5
print(policyGradient[5][10][15]) // Expected output being 0.5.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dict-of-dict-of-dicts, but if you don't need to index on any particular state input, you could just use a dict with tuples of keys:

```py
gradient = dict()

gradient[5,10,15] = 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that right now and mark that as the answer if it works :D

Edit:
Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

its a bit hacky

```
import collections
magic = lambda:collections.defaultdict(magic)
dd = magic()
dd[5] = 6
dd[6][7][7]=67
print(dd[6][7][7])
```